# pip install command causes Broken toolchain error

Tags: tensorflow

Installing TensorFlow with `pip install` generates several messages, ending with a `Broken toolchain` error.  Here's part of the transcript:

```
...<lots of warnings and errors>

You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements, please run 
'xcodebuild -license' (for user-level acceptance) or  
'sudo xcodebuild -license' (for system-wide acceptance) from within a 
Terminal window to review and agree to the Xcode license agreements.

...<more stack trace output>

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 653, in get_mathlib_info

    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")

RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that the 
[Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) build tools are installed on your system, 
but you haven't yet accepted the license agreements. To resolve this issue, do either of the following:

1. Open [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) and
   accept the license agreement.
2. Invoke the following command:

   ```
   xcodebuild -license
   ```

   See 
   [xcodebuild documentation](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) for more details.